# Removing special characters from CSV file in R

Tags: r, csv, character

I have a CSV file that includes special characters that I want to remove using R, so I can perform a word count.

By special characters I mean; ! " £ $ % ^ & * () -_ + = [ ] { } : ; ' @ # ~ ? . , > < \ |

I have seen a few tutorials online but I am unsure which one to follow. Please could someone advise (with code), how to remove such characters.

```
MyData <-read.csv(file="F:\\All.csv", header=TRUE, sep="," 
MyData
```

[Picture of CSV file with special characters I want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rTo8.png)

Comment: The file in the picture seems to be a text file not a cvs file which you can read with readLines()

Comment: it is definitely a CSV file and reads ok in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to only keep numbers and letters

```
library(stringr)

m = "ll#$@$!@hjgds fsd f#!#!@"

paste(unlist(str_extract_all(m, '[0-9a-zA-Z ]+')),collapse = '')
```

Comment: ok, so after performing the above code it prints out "Hi ""

How do I get it to print out my text, (without any special characters) using the above code

Kind Regards

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: the result is something from m = "ok this code removes spaces in between words?????????????? "'code' to "okthiscoderemovesspacesinbetweenwords". Help? I want to keep the spaces in between the words

Comment: @tastatham fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You could try treating them as `NA` values during import using the following example:

```
read.csv(file=file="F:\\All.csv", header=TRUE, na.strings=c("!","$") )
```